# Changing data in display tag table based on condition

Tags: jsp, servlets, struts2, jstl, displaytag

I am displaying data using `display-tag` like

```
<display:table  export="true" keepStatus="true" sort="external"
                id="CUSt" class="table_1_outer" style="width:98%" 
                name="requestScope.results.rows"  pagesize="25">
```

where results is a `RowSetDynaClass` object.

I have two fields like

```
<display:column property="CUST_CREATION_FLAG" title="Cust Verification" sortable="false" />
<display:column property="ACC_CREATION_FLAG" title="SB Acc. Verification" />
```

The value for these fields is either *Y* or *N*

My requirement is that when we have value N then that Value should be displayed in red color.

I tried doing something like this using `JSTL`

```
<c:if test="${CUSt.CUST_CREATION_FLAG eq dynaBeans[${results.CUST_CREATION_FLAG}].value }">
    <display:column property="CUST_CREATION_FLAG" title="Cust 
             Verification" style="color:red"  sortable="false"  />
```

But I got following error

```
"${CUSt.CUST_CREATION_FLAG eq dynaBeans[${results.CUST_CREATION_FLAG}].value }" 
contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Error Parsing: 
${CUSt.CUST_CREATION_FLAG eq dynaBeans[${results.CUST_CREATION_FLAG}].value }
```

Comment: remove the `$` sign inside dayBeans  `"${CUSt.CUST_CREATION_FLAG eq dynaBeans[$results.CUST_CREATION_FLAG].value }"` - --tell me if work

Answer (score 0):

You may try OGNL

```
<s:if test="#attr.CUSt.CUST_CREATION_FLAG eq dynaBeans[#attr.results.CUST_CREATION_FLAG].value">
   <display:column property="CUST_CREATION_FLAG" title="Cust Verification" style="color:red"  sortable="false"  />
</s:if>
```